# Rotate video according to rotation metadata and strip off metadata using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotation, metadata

I've got a video with the following metadata:

```
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2018-12-03T16:13:47.000000Z
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

And I would like to remove this metadata and rotate the video by whatever rotation value is found there (in this case -90 but it can be anything).

The result will be a video with the correct orientation and that works with all video players (including those that don't auto-rotate based on the metadata).

I've tried various commands but couldn't find anything that would work. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: FFmpeg does this automatically since v2.7

Comment: Using which command?

Comment: No switch required. e.g. `ffmpeg -i rotated.mp4 upright.mp4` will do it. Note that the video can't be streamcopied.

Comment: Oh well I've tried so many complicated commands and that simple one is indeed the solution. Thanks @Gyan, feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this, as @Gyan mentioned, is simply to run ffmpeg command without any parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i rotated.mp4 upright.mp4
```

That will strip off the rotation tag and recreate the video with the correct orientation.